# What's the difference between pkg, pkg-bin and pkg-git on the AUR?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, repository, aur

For example, there's

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/github-desktop/,

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/github-desktop-bin/, and

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/github-desktop-git/.

I took a look at the pkgbuilds and found no easily identifiable difference between the packages. This isn't just one package, but many of them. What's the difference between them? Which one should I install?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- Normal packages are built from stable versions or stable git tags of a repository. The program is compiled in user's machine and then installed. This will take time.
- Packages with `-bin` suffix are already built by upstream maintainer and is available somewhere. So, users do not have to compile the package in their machine. The `PKGBUILD` script downloads, extracts and install the files. Some proprietary software are released in this format where source code is not available.
- Packages with `-git` suffix are built from the latest commit from git repository, no matter it is a stable or not. This way user get latest fix or patches. This also compiled in user machine, then installed.

The difference among the AUR packages can be easily understood from their corresponding `PKGBUILD` file (shell script like) in `source()` function. Here is an example:

- For [`github-desktop`](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=github-desktop) the source is a stable git *release* tag:

```
pkgver=x.y.z
_pkgver="${pkgver}-linux1"
gitname="release-${_pkgver}"
https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop.git#tag=${gitname}
```

- For [`github-desktop-bin`](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=github-desktop-bin) the source is a *already packed* Debian package:

```
pkgver=x.y.z
_pkgver="${pkgver}-linux1"
gitname="release-${_pkgver}"
https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases/download/${gitname}/GitHubDesktop-linux-${_pkgver}.deb
```

- For [`github-desktop-git`](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=github-desktop-git) the source is *latest master* branch:

```
https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop.git
```

### Further readings:

- [Arch Wiki: Arch User Repository (AUR)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository)
- [Manjaro Forum: The difference between bin and non bin packages](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-bin-and-non-bin-packages/40884/)

Answer (score 2):

`-bin` indicates that it will install a binary instead of compile locally.

`-git` indicates that it will pull directly from `git` to get the most updated version (this implies that the version lacking `-git` is a bit more conservative and has been tested).